# Create a Transparent NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am wondering how do we create a UINavigationBar that is totally transparent (alpha = 0) but the BarButton Item is still visible.

I would like to have an Invisible NavigationBar but I need the BarButtonItem to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screenshot

[image]

Swift

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.new(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.new()
```

OC

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Comment: This doesn't work, however this eliminates the bar's shadow, but the Color of the bar is still there. Thanks anyway

Comment: Do you set background color of navigationBar,It works well for me as the screenshot I post

Comment: I had this in my code ->  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None; Once I remove that it actually works. thankss

Comment: Btw: `.new()` is not available in Swift  2.0 (Xcode beta 5).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:

Create a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and give it to the navigation controller to use it.

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    // An empty implementation will make the view to be transparent
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    }
}
```

If you are using InterfaceBuilder then you can select the navigation controller, then select its navigation bar, then change its class appropriately.

If you are doing it programatically:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: NavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
...
```

Result with an UIBarButtonItem:

[image]

Hope it helps

---

**Old Answer:**

I tried long time ago (ios6). Basically it is possible.
Make the color of navigation bar to be `UIColor.clearColor()`. Buttons will need to be custom UIViews inside the UIBarButton so the show the way you want. I think you will need to adjust the color of the view behind the navigation bar too.

Comment: UIColor.clear color makes the UINavigationBar becomes black. Thanks anyway